# Altium : sharing schematics beetween several pcb with different component ref or footprint

Tags: altium

I'm designing several boards which share some common features like a lipo undervoltage protection. I put this feature in a schematic and this schematic is used in several projects. That works pretty well.

Now, for one of the boards, I need to change a ref (and a footprint) of a component because the requirements are not the same. In my case, current is higher so I need a bigger MOS but everything else is the same.

Is there a way to do it without duplicating the schematic? I tried with variants. I was able to change the reference and the footprint but the changes are not visible in the PCB layout.

Comment: You say the changes weren't visible in the PCB layout. Did you make sure the variant was set to the correct one within the PCB viewer?

Comment: Yes. Since I also tried to se the variant as an "alternate part" but the result is the same...

Comment: I'm not sure you can change footprints in PCBs using variants. I've never tried that before, but logically it wouldn't make much sense. What if the footprints were, say, a SOT23 vs. a TO-92. If you change the footprint you'd also have to change the tracks leading to it, and that's a completely different board, not just an assembly variant. PCB variants are generally intended for replacing components with other components that have the same footprint. You'll probably need to duplicate your schematic, I'm afraid